# Iterate over fixed list efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, iteration

We have such a code:

```
var animals = new List<Animal> { lion, bird, mouse};
foreach(var animal in animals) ....
```

This code is in a performance critical part of the project, so I want to do it efficiently. I dont want to produce any memory garbage, because such an operation does not actually need memory allocation. So I want to avoid creating a new List or all that LINQ stuff. What I ideally want is such a code:

```
foreach(var animal in { lion, bird, mouse})  ...
```

Of course this does not compile. Is there a way to do this without producing any memory garbage?

p.s: I would also like to avoid polluting any namespace outside of the function.

Comment: Why don't you create this array or list once and reuse it in the loop? You can declare it as field in the class.

Comment: What will be your container? Don't you wanna use an array at the least?

Comment: @TimSchmelter your suggestion makes a lot of sense. But as I have stated in the question's p.s. I would like to avoid polluting any namespace. What I ideally want is a local static variable, like in C++. I guess we dont have it in C# and I have to live with it.

Comment: @Ephraim The container type does not matter as long as I do an efficient iteration.

Comment: @tupcuhamdi: you don't _pollute_ our namespace if you have a `private List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal> { lion, bird, mouse};` at class level. It's not even accessible or visible from outside. You can make it `static readonly` too if you want

Answer (score 1):

If its a fixed list, its known and its performance critical, then don't iterate to begin with:

```
var lion = ....;
var bird = ....;
var mouse = ....;

process(lion);
process(bird);
process(mouse);

//if the fixed list is not too long
//consider using [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void Process(Animal animal) { ... }
```

I'm intrigued to know what performance critical code this is, that you can't pay the price of allocating once a fixed array and then iterating it normally all the times you need to.

Comment: What if the OP has 150 animals? this is going to be very ugly and redundant code, not to mention writing it in the first place.

Comment: @guy I agree, but the requirement is: performance above all. When you are in that kind of situation, code readability, maintainability and aesthetics go down the drain. We don't have enough information to evaluate if its necessary to go to these extremes, but based upon the OPs question, it would seem so.

Comment: As @Guy says, the real data is very long and hand-crafted.

Comment: @tupcuhamdi well, make a decision. Do you want every ounce of performance you can possible get or are you willing to sacrifice it in lieu of maintainability? If the real data is very long, I'm not sure how you were thinking of iterating an "in place" collection in a readable way either.

Comment: Speed, Price, Quality: pick any two.  Or in the case of computer code, CPU, RAM, Readability: pick any two.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array, but it's only marginally better than a list:

```
 foreach(var animal in new[] { lion, bird, mouse})  ...
```

Also, like Tim commented, you could create the array in advance instead of every single call. So as a private static read-only field.

If performance is essential you should create a separate private function, or in C#7 you could create a local function. See https://garywoodfine.com/c-local-functions/

```
 function a()
 {
     function mylocalfunction(Animal animal)
     {
         //...
     }
     mylocalfunction(lion);
     mylocalfunction(bird);
     //...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make use of lamda expression though they are not performance efficient but solves your query.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

list.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Comment: Lambdas are just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the [most part](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/195082), it doesn't offer any *performance* improvements when compiled.